Microsoft Edge Show downloads menu when a download starts disabled for all users
I have an app on kiosk mode on Microsoft Edge and for this business the user needs to download files, however the prompt does not need to show up: Setting I want disabld by default
I want to disable by default the downloads menu from Microsoft Edge when a download starts, preferably from
According to this link, Microsoft Edge does not have a registry for this. Any other way to achieve this?
Also tried with javascript, found nothing, is it possible to hide with javscript the download?

It doesn't seem like it'd be a good idea to be able to disable a user's downloads menu via javascript. I don't think that's likely possible; that's a user/browser setting that the user gets to control.

The link you posted does have an answer for this - have you tried it? Read the second post from user Limitless Technology. About EnableSavePrompt etc..

The question here is why you don't want to show the download menu?

The download menu can only be controlled by the setting "Show downloads menu when a download starts". There's also no group policy or registry settings for this purpose. You can't configure it via JavaScript, because it is controlled by browser itself.
I suggest you request such a group policy for the download menu management. Just use Alt+Shift+I to send feedback to the Dev Team.
